# Set Color on CSS selector. Child and parent not compatible

Tags: css

I want to change the a link color to red and put a margin on li. The problem is it stay on the default set up on wordpress.

I tryed:

```
#menu-menu-raiq a{color:red;}
#menu-menu-raiq li{margin:5px;}
```

but nothing work. I also tryed with the class.

```
a{color:red;background-color:blue;}
```

work but it's for all the page.

```
<div class="off-canvas-wrapper-inner" data-off-canvas-wrapper>
    <div class="off-canvas position-right" id="off-canvas" data-off-canvas data-position="right">
        <ul id="menu-menu-raiq" class="vertical menu" data-accordion-menu><li id="menu-item-169" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-169"><a href="http://dev.wdp.raiq.ca/a-propos/">À propos</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-129" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-129"><a href="http://dev.wdp.raiq.ca/activites/">Activités</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-130" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-130"><a href="http://dev.wdp.raiq.ca/formations/">Formations</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-126" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-126"><a href="http://dev.wdp.raiq.ca/ressources/">Ressources</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-128" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-128"><a href="http://dev.wdp.raiq.ca/membres/">Membres</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-125" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-125"><a href="http://dev.wdp.raiq.ca/contact/">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
#main-menu-raiq li.menu-item {
  margin:5px !important;
}

#main-menu-raiq li.menu-item a {
  color:red !important;
  background-color:blue !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to ensure that your specific styles are applied, you can use the [`!important`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#The_!important_exception) modifier in CSS to give them a higher specificity value.

So if you wanted to target the `<li>` and `<a>` elements beneath your `main-menu-raiq` element, you could use something like the following:

```
/* Explicitly add 5px of left margin to <li> elements beneath your main menu */
#main-menu-raiq li { 
    margin-left: 5px!important; 
}
/* Likewise, explicitly target any <a> elements beneath your menu and make them red/blue */
#main-menu-raiq a { 
    color: red!important; 
    background: blue!important; 
}
```